# How to make certain apps not be affected by your theme?

Tags: themes

I'm using the Arc theme for Ubuntu, and for most apps it is beautiful. My problem is that for some, it makes them unusable.

I just setup Enpass for password management. But the Arc theme makes it so hard to use, from a visual perspective.

So what can I do to fix this? I want to exclude specific apps from the theme entirely.

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.1.